# Symfony Semantical Error

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting this error: (before everything was ok, but after some changes it started to appear)

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Expose" in property VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Slider::$name was never imported.
>
> Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Code is here:

```
<?php

namespace VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\SliderImage;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Traits\IdentificationalEntity;
use VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Traits\NamedEntity;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
 
/**
 * Slider
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Repository\SliderRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Slider
{
    use IdentificationalEntity;
    use NamedEntity;

    /**
     * @var SliderImage
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SliderImage", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * 
     */
    protected  $slides;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->slides = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    
    /**
     * Get all slides
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getSlides()
    {
        return $this->slides;
    }

}
```

NamedEntity file code:

```
<?php
namespace VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Traits;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Class NamedEntity
 * @package VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Traits
 */
trait NamedEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(min="3")
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $name;


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return File
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Cant figure it out what is wrong...

Comment: Post code of `VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\AbstractEntity\File`. Because it is stated in the error;-)

Comment: Sorry, error was on VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Slider I edited error message

Comment: most possibly the error is at  `VswSystem\CmsBundle\Entity\Traits\NamedEntity;`

Comment: @john Smith I added NamedEntity file code

Comment: yeah as u see there is the use statement missing, just add it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message exactly point you to the concrete error.

You need omit `@Expose` annotation in $name field definition or add `use` statement where add link to Expose class.

If you use `Expose` from JMS Serializer bundle you should add next line:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
```